# Calling a function from another PHP script via HTTP: is it slower or anything else?

Tags: php, function, coding-style

Let's say I have a PHP file `some_function.php` which I can run with `file_get_contents('some_function.php?' . $parameters_string)` (or any similar function). The parameters to this function can be given via either GET or POST HTTP method.

Instead I could `include` needed file and use this function within one script.

I could figure out that it could be reasonable if I need to run a separate process or I need this function to be on a separate server. But if not, is there any reasons not to do it? May be this call will be much slower? Anything else I should take into account?

I know that I will not be able to use global variables (which I assume as a bad coding style anyway).

Answer (score 1):

By using `file_get_contents()` you will not be actually calling the function in question but will make an `HTTP` request passing some predefined parameters which will then be passed on the function in your code.

Using `include()` you could have a library of `classes` or `functions` inside that file, and call them directly as needed and as many times as needed.

**EXAMPLE:**

*library.php*

```
function my_function_1() { }
function my_function_2() { }
```

**index.php**

```
include('library.php');

my_function_1();   // call the first function
my_function_2();   // call the second function
my_function_1();   // call the first function again, just because we can
```

You wouldn't be able to do that through the `HTTP` request and even if you did `hardcode` your `some_function.php` file to do some functionality like above, you would end up with really bad code that would be hard to customize to your needs and near impossible to maintain once it gets bigger.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass a query string via a local `file_get_contents` call as shown.

If you use `file_get_contents` on a remote HTTP URL, you will be able to use a query string, but this will be significantly slower than a local `include` or `file_get_contents`.

You can, incidentally, still `include` something that needs `$_GET`/`$_POST` variables:

```
<?php

$_GET['something'] = true;

include('something.php');
```

Comment: Hm, I'm surprised: it's really not working! Is that correct I need to pass the query string via `context` parameter of `file_get_context`?

Comment: No, you don't need a context to pass a query string in a HTTP request.